# Web application navigation considerations

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, progressive-web-apps, browser-history

I've slowly but steadily been learning HTML, CSS, Javascript, AJAX, PHP and MYSQL and have built a simple website designed for mobile phones. It has pretty basic functionality, allowing the user to add entries to a database and modify them.  I use buttons and modals to let the user interact. The goal is to have it behave like similar to a native app in fullscreen without me having to learn building actual apps on Android and Apple so I was thinking about using a PWA.

But how do I handle navigation? Should PWA's always be a one page app? I have only a couple "views" or pages but I need to keep track of some data across those different pages.

When the user presses the back button in a PWA it closes the app on mobile. It would be nice to have the back button close a modal for example, like you would expect in a regular app.  But after some research this apparently is not possible.

I can use multiple pages: index.html, list.html and the back button will behave as expected but I want the app to exit when the back button is pressed on the index page. When the user has visited: index, then list, then index and now presses the back button it will first go through their whole history.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: You should take a look at the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). There is also the [Navigation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API) but it is not that supported yet.